# Problem when converting a blade file to pdf using Dom PDF

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, dompdf

For some reason the bootstrap 4 css libraries and even my custom fonts are not rendered when trying to convert a blade file to a pdf.

This is how it should be rendered :

### [image]

But this is how it is actually rendered :

[image]

This is the html code of my template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: "A DAY WITHOUT SUN";
                src: url("/vendor/fonts/A DAY WITHOUT SUN.otf");
            }
            .customer {
                font-family: "A DAY WITHOUT SUN",Verdana,sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 3em;
            }
            .header,.date {
                font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
                color: purple;
            }
            .date {
                font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
                color: purple;
                text-align: right;
            }
            .mealTitle {
                font-family: "A DAY WITHOUT SUN",Verdana,sans-serif;
                font-size: 4em;
                color: purple;
            }
            .mealContent {
                font-family: "A DAY WITHOUT SUN",Verdana,sans-serif;
                font-size: 3em;
                color: #4d3d3d;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 50px;
            }
            .calories {
                color: saddlebrown;
            }
            .carbs {
                color: darkgreen;
            }
            .proteins {
                color: orangered;
            }
            .fats {
                color: dodgerblue;
            }
            .nutritionalValuesMeal {
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

{{--    Menu header--}}
        <div style="padding-bottom: 70px" class="container">
            <div class="row">
{{--                Menu image--}}
                <div class="col" align="center">
                    <img width="500" src="/logo-big.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
{{--                Dear customer...--}}
                <div style="padding-top: 50px;" class="col">
                    <p style="color:purple; font-size: 1.5em" class="text-center header">DEAR</p>
                    <p style="color:purple" class="text-center customer">{{ $customerName }}</p>
                    <p style="color: rgba(87,43,0,0.5); font-size: 1.5em" class="text-center header">We hope you will enjoy this healthy day !</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

{{--Header total nutritional values--}}
        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div style="font-size: 1em" class="row">
{{--                        Calories--}}
                        <div class="col calories">
                            <span id="calories">{{ $totalCalories }}</span><br/>
                            KCAL
                        </div>
{{--                        Carbs--}}
                        <div class="col carbs">
                            <span id="carbs">{{ $pctCarbs }}%</span><br/>
                            CARBS
                        </div>
{{--                        Proteins--}}
                        <div class="col proteins">
                            <span id="proteins">{{ $pctProteins }}%</span><br/>
                            PROTEINS
                        </div>
{{--                        Fats--}}
                        <div class="col fats">
                            <span id="fats">{{ $pctFats }}%</span><br/>
                            FATS
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
{{--                Date--}}
                <div style="font-size: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-left: 50px" class="col date">
                    {{ $date }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

{{--Meals--}}
    <div class="container border border-dark">
{{--        Breakfast--}}
        @if($breakfastContent != '')
        <div style="padding-top: 50px;padding-bottom: 50px;" class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="mealTitle">BREAKFAST</span>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around nutritionalValuesMeal">
                    <span class="calories">{{ $caloriesBreakfast }}</span>
                    <span class="carbs">{{ $carbsBreakfast }}g</span>
                    <span class="proteins">{{ $proteinsBreakfast }}g</span>
                    <span class="fats">{{ $fatsBreakfast }}g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mealContent">
                {{ $breakfastContent }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
{{--        Snack 1--}}
        @if($snack1Content != '')
        <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="mealTitle">1<sup>st</sup> SNACK</span>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around nutritionalValuesMeal">
                    <span class="calories">{{ $caloriesSnack1 }}</span>
                    <span class="carbs">{{ $carbsSnack1 }}g</span>
                    <span class="proteins">{{ $proteinsSnack1 }}g</span>
                    <span class="fats">{{ $fatsSnack1 }}g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mealContent">
                {{ $snack1Content }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
        {{--        Lunch--}}
        @if($lunchContent != '')
        <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="mealTitle">LUNCH</span>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around nutritionalValuesMeal">
                    <span class="calories">{{ $caloriesLunch }}</span>
                    <span class="carbs">{{ $carbsLunch }}g</span>
                    <span class="proteins">{{ $proteinsLunch }}g</span>
                    <span class="fats">{{ $fatsLunch }}g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mealContent">
                {{ $lunchContent }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
{{--        Snack 2--}}
        @if($snack2Content != '')
        <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="mealTitle">2<sup>nd</sup> SNACK</span>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around nutritionalValuesMeal">
                    <span class="calories">{{ $caloriesSnack2 }}</span>
                    <span class="carbs">{{ $carbsSnack2 }}g</span>
                    <span class="proteins">{{ $proteinsSnack2 }}g</span>
                    <span class="fats">{{ $fatsSnack2 }}g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mealContent">
                {{ $snack2Content }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
{{--        Dinner--}}
        @if($dinnerContent != '')
        <div style="padding-bottom: 50px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="mealTitle">DINNER</span>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-around nutritionalValuesMeal">
                    <span class="calories">{{ $caloriesDinner }}</span>
                    <span class="carbs">{{ $carbsDinner }}g</span>
                    <span class="proteins">{{ $proteinsDinner }}g</span>
                    <span class="fats">{{ $fatsDinner }}g</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col mealContent">
                {{ $dinnerContent }}
            </div>
        </div>
            @endif
    </div>


    </body>

    <script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Do you know how could I load the CSS libraries and the custom fonts ?

Thanks for the help !